# How did Apple create the blur behind the album cover in Apple Music?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview

It seems to be a blurred shadow, but I can't seem to find the right tools to re-create this. I've looked at `ciImage` but don't know a good way to start it. Guidance would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Apple Music Album Blurred Background]

Comment: Just visually eyeing things up - and with some knowledge that you can **chain** various CI filters (use the output of one as the input for thenext) - I'll wager they are (1) using a blur to "expand the bottom-most layer (notice the gold in the upper left) then (2) layering a few things on top of it (this **isn't CI**) like a slightly curved white layer then on top of that the album (is that what they call it anymore?) artwork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You could use UIImage and **Core Image Filters** (CIFilters) to achieve the effect.

By using two **UIImageViews** with the same image (or programatically duplicating the cover ImageView) and then applying a **CIGaussianBlurFilter** and a **CIExposureAdjust** to the one on the background.

If you do it right, it could look like this. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Plain HTML, CSS, & JS.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/livehelp/pen/yLXmqWB?editors=1000

Important: To see the reflection positioned properly below, don't use the blue "Run Code Snippet" button. Instead, click the blue "Expand Snippet" link & then click the blue "Run Code Snippet" button.

```html
<style>
body {margin: 5%;}  
img { width:300px; position:relative; z-index:1; border-radius: 10px; }  
#srblur {
position:relative;
transform: translate(-100%, 7%) scale(1.1);
z-index:0;
filter: blur(20px);
opacity:0.7;
}
</style>
<img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71-S-DJ5YML._SL1000_.jpg" />
<script>  
  var elmnt = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
  var cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);
  document.body.appendChild(cln);
  cln.id = "srblur";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using `UIVisualEffectView`

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)
let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect:blurEffect)
visualEffectView.frame = imageView.bounds
imageView.addSubview(visualEffectView) // album artwork imageview,
```

Comment: I think this will only blur the art cover. Also, it seems like the background is a shadow path with a huge radius; somehow the color of the shadow path is the color of the artwork. I tried `artworkImage.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)`, but it just shows the image as it is.

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/NobelLiu/NLImageColor/blob/master/NLImageColor/NLImageColor.swift